# Function or method to find the Similarity and Differences in the Layers of Two DNNs

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

I have two deep neural networks (DNNs) with 15 layers, that one of them is the fine-tuned (only 5 final layers) version of the other to works for specific text classifications.

How can we effectively measure and evaluate the level of similarity and differences in the 10th layers of DNNs? I mean if I feed a common input X, and see the differnt output, is there any way to see what are the diffrences between the layer 10th of the original DNNs and the fine-tuned ones?
Is there any techniques to conduct a apply for comparative analysis of these specific layers?